# isset($_POST['submit']) not being triggered on button click

Tags: php, html

The below code should echo when a user clicks on "more". I can't see the issue with the below code, so any assistance will be much appreciated.

```
if (isset($_POST['more'])){
        echo <<<saveNewFactor
        <input type="text" size="29">
        saveNewFactor;
}

echo <<<saveNewFactor
    </br>
    <input type="submit" neme="more" value="more" class="forming7">
saveNewFactor;
```

Comment: Typo: `'neme' != 'name'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML:

```
<input type="submit" neme="more" value="more" class="forming7">
```

You have spelt name as neme, change it to:

```
<input type="submit" name="more" value="more" class="forming7">
```

Comment: yes you are correct name is miss-spelled

Comment: thank you. now it only echoes an input when "more" is clicked for the first time. just once.

Comment: When it's been clicked, the PHP will have been triggered, refreshing the page would make it work again. Otherwise, you would need to look at an AJAX route to have the front end react with the back end continuously. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_php.asp

Comment: Nice of you helping out. But questions that are solved by correcting a typo should be solved with a comment and closed.